# Views Field Views "crashes" my view

Tags: views

I installed VFV as recommended in one of the questions here, as it seems to be exactly what I need for complex listings. But now my View used to list content nodes bound to a specific term stopped listing them.

Before I wrote that statement I uninstalled the VFV module and the View began working back again. I repeated that operation twice for certainty sake.

Maybe I'm overlooking some option somewhere, but why would one module actually impact the other?

I wouldn't like to give up VFV, really.

Comment: If you can't nail it down, "all" VFV is doing is calling views_embed_view(....) for you, so this could be accomplished with a really simple views field template

Comment: I will try with View Field to see if it does the job, but anyway I doubt the VFV is as innocent itself as you say. It might be some kind of argument inheritance setting, which I haven't found so far.